# How can I source a file into a list in the global environment

Tags: r

I have the following requirement: I have a list of variables and functions defined in a `config.R` file:

```
# config.R
x <- 1
foo <- function(y) {
    2
}
z <- x + 1
```

I want the above to be "sourced" in a list defined in the `.Globalenv`
I have a way to do this by creating a local environment:

```
source_in_list <- function(path) {
    e <- new.env()
    source(path, local = e)
    return(as.list(e))
}

p <- source_in_list("config.R")
p
$x
[1] 1

$z
[1] 2

$foo
function(y) {
        2
}
<environment: 0x2f99d90>
```

My problem is that foo is linked to the `<environment: 0x2f99d90>`, which means if I was to redefine `foo` in the `.Globalenv` `p$foo` would be unaffected, and this is not what I want.
Essentially, I would like to do as if I was:

- creating p in `.Globalenv`
- executing every line `within` p

so result would be like:

```
p
$x
[1] 1

$z
[1] 2

$foo
function(y) {
        2
}
```

How can I do this ?

**EDIT:**

I realized that what I wanted was define functions from the source file in the globalenv() and the rest in a list

```
source_in_list <- function(path) {                                                                                                                                                                                                             
    e <- new.env()                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
    source(path, local = e)                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    # types                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    is_fun <- sapply(e, FUN = function(x) inherits(x, "function"))                                                                                                                                                                             
    # define functions from e into globalenv                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    if(any(is_fun)) {                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
        for(fun_name in names(which(is_fun))) {                                                                                                                                                                                                
            # assign in globalenv                                                                                                                                                                                                              
            assign(x = fun_name, value = eval(parse(text = deparse(get(fun_name, envir = e))), envir = globalenv()), envir = globalenv())                                                                                                      
            # remove from local env                                                                                                                                                                                                            
            rm(list = fun_name, envir = e)                                                                                                                                                                                                     
        }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    return(as.list(e))                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
p1 <- source_in_list("config.R")

p1
$x
[1] 1

$z
[1] 2

foo
function (y) 
{
    2
}
>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have a misconception:  if `foo` is stored in your list `p`, then redefining `foo` in `.Globalenv` won't have any effect.  Those will be separate objects.

The purpose of the environment associated with a function is to tell R where to look for non-local variables used in the function.  Your original version will end up with two copies of everything you sourced, one in the list and one in the local environment you created.  If `foo` referred to `x`, it would see the one in the local environment.  For example, look at this change to your code where `foo()` returns `x`:

```
# config.R
x <- 1
foo <- function() {
   x 
}
z <- x + 1
```

and then

```
source_in_list <- function(path) {
    e <- new.env()
    source(path, local = e)
    return(as.list(e))
}

p <- source_in_list("config.R")
x <- 42         # Set a global variable x
p$foo()         
# [1] 1         # It is ignored

p$x <- 123      # Set x in p
p$foo()         
# [1] 1         # It is ignored
```

You probably don't want two copies of everything.  But then it's not clear that what you want to do is possible.  A list can't act as the environment of a function, so there's no way to make `p$x` be the target of references from within `foo`.

I'd suggest that instead of returning a list, you just return the local environment you created.  Then things will work as you'd expect:

```
source_to_local <- function(path) {
  e <- new.env()
  source(path, local = e)
  return(e)
}

e <- source_to_local("config.R")
x <- 42      # set a global
e$foo()
[1] 1        # it is ignored

e$x <- 123   # set x in e
e$foo()
[1] 123      # it responds
```

The main disadvantage of returning the environment is that they don't print the way lists do, but you could probably write a function to print an environment and make everything in it visible.

Comment: You're right I don't know how I got this idea the functions within the list could be defined within the list and also in `.Globalenv`. What I think I now need is a way to read a file, and define the functions in `.Globalenv` then in the list, the "ordinary variables" can stay in the list.

Comment: I just did this and added an EDIT